# Popen works on system but fails on Django

Tags: python, django, macos

OSX 10.7.5, System Python 2.7.1, Django 1.5.1

In system Python shell:

```
from subprocess import Popen 
Popen("open /Library/Application\ Support/blender.app", shell=True)
```

will open blender.

`Django views.py Popen("open /Library/Application\ Support/blender.app", shell=True)` will open blender, quit unexpectedly and report fatal python error.

I think that Django/Python 2.7 is conflicting with blender's Python 3.2. How would I fix this?

Comment: Can you post full trackback?

Comment: spawning GUI apps on the server from within a web app seems like a really awful idea (and if django's running as a user that has access to the console that's an additional awful idea); what are you hoping to accomplish?

Comment: I am trying to use blender background function to create webgl files which can be shown in three.js. It works programmatically within blender and manually thru django.

Comment: Exception Type:  EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000002, 0x0000000000000000

Application Specific Information:
dyld: launch, loading dependent libraries

Dyld Error Message:
  Symbol not found: __cg_jpeg_resync_to_restart
  Referenced from: /Users/USER/*/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libTIFF.dylib
  Expected in: /Users/USER/*/libJPEG.dylib
 in /Users/USER/*/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libTIFF.dylib

Comment: Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x00007fff8e767ce2 __pthread_kill + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib              0x00007fff8ff137d2 pthread_kill + 95
2   org.blenderfoundation.blender  0x0000000102e17726 abort + 22
3   org.blenderfoundation.blender  0x00000001011daab0 Py_FatalError + 80
4   org.blenderfoundation.blender  0x00000001011daa37 _Py_InitializeEx_Private + 1271
5   org.blenderfoundation.blender  0x00000001009a99fc BPY_python_start + 140
6   org.blenderfoundation.blender  0x000000010013dd38 WM_init + 216